# Extract Video Frames as HEIC/HEIF images

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-11

How do I extract frames from videos as heif/heic images? I want to use ffmpeg but they don't support it. What other tools can do the trick?

Comment: [Build](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MinGW) FFmpeg from sources with [libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif). Add `--enable-libheif` build flag... Let us know if HEIF image encoder is working.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please note that asking for tool/software recommendations is specifically off topic on this site. What research have you done regarding this prior to asking and what have you tried?